# jQuery DataTable FixedHeader does not work in scroll-able container

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I'm using Bootstrap and jQuery Datables.
My table sits inside a containing div (#dataContainer)

By itself, FixedHeader work just fine.
However, if I make the container fixed height and scrollable, my datatable's fixedheader does not work anymore.
Bit too stupid to wrap my head around this.  :-) so hope the following code help (all fine if I do NOT call "setupScrolling")

```
  setupDataTables() {
    $('.datatable').DataTable( {
      "paging":     false,
      "searching":  false,
      "scrollX":    true,
      "info":       false,
      order:        [[ 1, "asc" ]],
      fixedHeader:  true
    });
  },

  // FIXED HEADER FOR ABOVE DATA TABLE DOES NOT WORK IF BELOW IS APPLIED TO THE DIV IT'S IN'
  setupScrolling() {
    if ($("#dataContainer").length ) {
        let content_height = $(window).height() - $("#dataContainer").offset().top -55;
        let otherheight = $("#dataContainer").height();
        if(otherheight > content_height) {
          $("#dataContainer").css({"max-height":content_height + 'px', "min-height":content_height + 'px'});
          $("#dataContainer").css({'overflow-x':'hidden','overflow-y':'scroll'});
        }
    }
  },
```

Comment: Also read the [docs](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/) : "*Please note that FixedHeader is not currently compatible with tables that have the scrolling features of DataTables enabled (scrollX / scrollY).*". Have seen this question so many times that I now just closes it. Feel free to reopen or elaborate to change the dupe-hammer.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for missing that in the  docs.